# Touch-pad suddenly stopped working Ubuntu 18.04.2 DELL Vostro

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, dell

I was working on my laptop and suddenly my touchpad stopped working.
Scrolling, left click,right click nothing is working now. However I tried attaching a mouse and it is working just fine.
I tried to reboot my laptop, it did not work an later checked my mouse system settings and they were just fine.

Also tried through terminal by running query - 
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
and changing line to -
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"`
and saved it and rebooted the system, still no help.

Comment: Go to `Mouse & Touchpad` settings and make sure the touchpad is enabled.

Comment: @heynnema already checked that one as well, seems fine there..

Comment: Do you have touchpad-indicator app or GNOME Shell extension installed? If so, has it disabled your touchpad as per its settings? Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: Also, after making changes to /etc/default/grub, you have to `sudo update-grub` and then reboot,

Comment: `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` I got no such file for this command.
And I did reboot the system post update grub command.That was the only solution I knew

Comment: To eliminate a software issue, boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the touchpad works. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, boot to it and try the touchpad there.

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and give me the model # and service tag # from the bottom of your computer.

Comment: @heynnema I am only using Ubuntu as of now. The bios version is A04. Model is Dell Vostro 3458 and service tag number is DY5ZC72.
I might have to create a flash drive in my pen drive to test the software issue

Comment: Yes, create the flash drive and test. Also see my answer about the BIOS. If it is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema By testing with flash drive you mean just booting once through drive or re-install Ubuntu through it?

Comment: No, just boot to a Ubuntu Live USB, and select "Try Ubuntu", and see if the TP works there.

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

Your BIOS is really old.

As per `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` you have version **A04**.

Using "Model is Dell Vostro 3458 and service tag number is DY5ZC72"...

**Note**: make sure you have a good backup before updating the BIOS.

The current version is **A15**, as per https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/0-eGtKRTR2MmdlSkorWWc4RmdHVWFtUT090/drivers

See https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln171755/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment?lang=en for how to do this in a Ubuntu-only environment.